# Cannot Fetch URL Cookie Information in JAVA code when running WebSphere v9 server - Connection Refused

Tags: java, cookies, servlets, websphere

I am having trouble fetching cookies information from an URL in Java web application. My goal is while my web page load, it runs a servlet filter for authentication. When running the servlet filter, I'm trying to fetch cookie information from another site (site that is not in my project) so it can authenticate the user to access my developed html site. When it ran "connection.getContent()" code, I received this error below.

> java.net.connectException: Connection refused

This only happens when running a web application. However, I tested the cookie fetch code in a JAVA Main Method and ran a simple JAVA application. It works and I see the cookie information from the site. I believe this is not a firewall related since the site I'm trying to fetch is under same network and running the simple JAVA application works. It may be WebSphere related.

I'm using a IBM WebSphere Application Server v9 and JAVA 8 code (work requirement). Also used java.net.* library for fetching cookie information. Eclipse is the tool that I'm using to develop web applications or JAVA application. I'm not a WebSphere expert or am I missing a step in java code, please help.

Here is the sample servlet filter code of fetching cookie information part.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {    
        try {       
            CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            URL url = new URL("https://somesite.com/");         
            HttpsURLConnection  connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.getContent();    
            CookieStore cookies = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
            List<HttpCookie> cookieList = cookies.getCookies();
              
            for (HttpCookie cookie : cookieList) {
              System.out.println("cookie name: " + cookie.getName());
              System.out.println("cookie comment: " + cookie.getComment());
              System.out.println("cookie doman: " + cookie.getDomain());
              System.out.println("cookie value: " + cookie.getValue());
              System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
              }     
        } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: ` Connection refused` usually means that there is no connection between your WAS host and target host. Try to use `curl` to verify that connection can be made. Maybe you have firewall issues.

Comment: The network that we are on is the same network for the site that I'm targeting. I dont think its a firewall related. I could be wrong. The site that I'm targeting is a login page where i need to retrieve its Cookie information. Since I'm running my site using WAS, I hit the error when it runs the url.openConnection() code. Could this be a TCP setting related in WAS? I've been trying research and get a understand on this.. Thank you for your response!